# How to convert wav with custom codec to mp3?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, codec, windows-media-player

I've received a set of `.wav` files which are encoded with a custom codec.  I wish to convert these files to `.mp3` (or really any standard audio format that other software will recognize).

The codec has been provided to me as a `.msi` file, which allows me to install the codec in Windows. Running the installer creates a `.acm` file (in its own folder, not in the standard codec location which seems to be `c:\windows\system32` ). Once I do so, Windows Media Player will play the audio in the files. No other software will play them (I've tried Audacity, VLC, QuickTime, ...).

I've tried to convert the files using ffmpeg, but it doesn't recognize the format either.

I've attempted the technique of burning the audio to a CD (with the intent of ripping the CD as mp3), but WMP gives an error when it attempts to burn them.

I'm proficient in Python and Javascript so I don't mind coding a solution if that's possible--I'm not really familiar with the theory of audio codecs.  I looked at a couple python libraries but they didn't seem able to do anything with the `.msi` file I've been given.

Can anyone suggest a solution?  Solutions might include:

- How to point ffmpeg or Audacity or VLC to the installed codec so that it is able to play/convert the files?
- Point me to some resources/libraries/code snippets for coding a converter based on the supplied `.acm` file?
- How to convice WMP to save these files in some other format?

Comment: Have you tried looking for converter, like [ACM Converter](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Convertors/ACM-Converter.shtml)?

Comment: @Rotem Thanks, I've tried various converters (including the one you linked), none of them can open these files .  I think part of the issue is that the codec hasn't installed in a "standard" way and the converter doesn't know to match up the file with the codec.  If there is a converter with the ability to tell it "use this codec file for decoding" it might help.

Comment: Can you enable [Stereo Mix](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) in your system? Do you want to try playing the files, and recording the the audio as described [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/record-system-sound-with-ffmpeg-on-windows-10/)?

Comment: @Rotem I had considered trying that; it might be a last resort: there are thousands of hours of audio in these files so I'd rather not convert them in real time.

Comment: I don't see any "supplied .acm file"